# R: which() function can't find specified string in character vector (vector DOES contain string)

Tags: r, vector, character

I wrote a simple function to scrape the names of all MLB pitchers from Baseball Reference.com.  I created a vector with the scraped names, removed the Â from the raw scraped names, and coerced into a character vector.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2016-standard-pitching.shtml"
mlbpitcherdata <- read_html(url)

mlbpitchers <- mlbpitcherdata %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>%  html_text()
mlbpitchers <- as.character(sapply(mlbpitchers, function(x) gsub("Â","",x))) # Remove "Â" from all raw pitcher names
```

I then tried to look for the indexes of specific names in the character vector which I knew were inside the vector, and the `which()` function returned `integer(0)`.

```
# Search for pitcher name in list of pitchers = Returns integer(0)!
which(mlbpitchers=="Chad Bettis")
integer(0)

# But, mlbpitchers CLEARLY has Chad Bettis inside of it.
mlbpitchers[26]
[1] "Chad Bettis"
```

I'm so confused as to why the `which()` function isn't identifying the name.  and I would really appreciate anyone's help.  I know it's probably something really stupid and easy, but I can't figure it out! Thank you!

(Note: Upon removing the Â character, I was asked to choose the encoding for saving.  I choose the system default: ISO 8859-1.  I'm not sure if this could play a role in the problem.)

Comment: `rawToChar(charToRaw(mlbpitchers[26]),multiple = TRUE)` probably illuminates the problem, but I'm not an expert on weird hidden characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. In particular, if you look at

```
R> substr(mlbpitchers[26], 1, 4) == "Chad"
[1] TRUE
R> substr(mlbpitchers[26], 5, 5) == " "
[1] FALSE
```

As Joran suggest, using

```
R> rawToChar(charToRaw(mlbpitchers[26]),multiple = TRUE)
[1] "C"    "h"    "a"    "d"    "\xc2" "\xa0" "B"    "e"    "t"    "t"   
[11] "i"    "s"
```

also highlights the problem. These characters (thanks Nicola) are html [non-breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) spaces. To remove them use

```
gsub("\xc2\xa0"," ",mlbpitchers)
```

Comment: Here is what I observe when I call what you said: `rawToChar(charToRaw(mlbpitchers[26]),multiple = TRUE)
 [1] "C" "h" "a" "d" " " "B" "e" "t" "t" "i" "s"`

Comment: These are non-breaking spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space To remove them: `gsub("\xc2\xa0"," ",mlbpitchers)`

Comment: @IRNotSmart  I don't get that. What happens when you compare the 5th character?

Comment: @csgillespie, @nicola `substr(mlbpitchers[26], 5, 5) == " "
[1] FALSE`  So confused here man.  I have no idea why I'm not seeing the `\xc2` and `\xao` when I call row to char

Comment: @IRNotSmart Two ideas: (1) Restart R and try again, (2) Share what platform you're on.

Comment: @joran Restarted R and computer, problem persists.  Running R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14). Confused af!  I wonder if I need to change the encoding somehow?  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at the file when you write the object to a csv file: `write.csv(mblpitchers[26], file="tmp.csv", row.names=F)`

Comment: @IRNotSmart By platform, I meant what OS you're running. It's a long shot, but I was wondering if there might be a difference between OSX, Linux, Windows.

Comment: I'm using a proper OS (Linux)

Comment: @joran Using Windows 7 OS- sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: @csgillespie `write.csv(mblpitchers[26], file="tmp.csv", row.names=F)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'mblpitchers' not found` Apparently doesnt want me to write the csv

Comment: Try `mlbpitchers` not `mbl`

Comment: @csgillespie `"x"
"Chad Bettis"` is written after writing to csv file.  The space in between the first and last name is red, with a period in the middle of it (not in normal period spot).  I opened the csv in Rstudio environment